# $\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx ?= \big(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\big)^2$

Tags: integration

I'm going to solve a problem. I reached to the following equation

$\int_{a}^{b}f(x)^2dx = \big(\int_{a}^{b}f(x)dx\big)^2$

Is is right?

Comment: Usually it is not right. But it also depends on $f$. How did you reach this?

Comment: @YujieZha Let X be a random variable and $E[X] = \lambda$. Indeed, my question is $\int_{a}^{b}(1-F_{X}(x))^2dx = (\int_{a}^{b}1-F_{X}(x)dx)^2$?

Comment: Note that $(\int{f(x)}dx)^2$ usually represents a double integral:
$\iint{f(x)f(y)}dxdy$

Comment: @HasanHeydari Hmm.. I do not see it to be necessarily true though. Maybe it's out of the scope of this question, but what is the motivation for you to have this guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think so.
Try substituting a simple function for $f(x)$, such as $f(x) = x^2$.
Using the indefinite integral (since you haven't changed the bounds), we get that $\int{x^2}^2dx = \int{x^4}dx = \frac{x^5}{5}$. However, ${(\int{x^2}dx)}^2 = \frac{x^6}{9}$.

Answer (score 4):

Generally,Not at all.

Consider integrating:

$$\int \sin ^2 x \text{ and } (\int \sin x)^2$$
with bounds, lets say $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$

You will get it.

Comment: Or simpler, just integrate $x$.

Comment: Indeed. @CameronWilliams

Answer (score 4):

Another more obvious counter example:

Consider $f(x) = 1$ on $(a,b)$, and $b-a \ne 1$, then

$$\int_a^b f(x)^2 \, dx = b - a \ne (b -a)^2 = \bigg(\int_a^b f(x) \,dx \bigg)^2$$